# Custom sort method in Python is not sorting list properly

Tags: python, list, sorting

I'm a student in a Computing class and we have to write a program which contains file handling and a sort. I've got the file handling done and I wrote out my sort (it's a simple sort) but it doesn't sort the list. My code is this:

```
namelist = []
scorelist = []
hs = open("hst.txt", "r")
namelist = hs.read().splitlines()
hss = open("hstscore.txt","r")
for line in hss:
    scorelist.append(int(line))




scorelength = len(scorelist)
for i in range(scorelength):
    for j in range(scorelength + 1):
        if scorelist[i] > scorelist[j]:
            temp = scorelist[i]
            scorelist[i] = scorelist[j]
            scorelist[j] = temp
            return scorelist
```

I've not been doing Python for very long so I know the code may not be efficient but I really don't want to use a completely different method for sorting it and we're not allowed to use .sort() or .sorted() since we have to write our own sort function. Is there something I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Your `return` statement is in the wrong spot.  In fact you don't need a return statement at all, unless all of this code in contained in a method or function

Comment: Do be aware that you have sorted the scores but not the names - the two lists are now out of sync with each other.

Comment: Since `i` and `j` aren't ordered relative to each other, your swaps won't be either. One simple change could make this a working variation of a bubble sort.

Comment: @MarkRansom Really? Would you be able to tell me it?

Comment: Always make sure `i` is less than `j`. And I'm probably wrong about it being a variation of bubble sort.

Comment: @MarkRansom I'm still not quite sure what you mean, what is the line(s) of code for that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def super_simple_sort(my_list):
    switched = True
    while switched:
        switched = False
        for i in range(len(my_list)-1):
            if my_list[i] > my_list[i+1]:
               my_list[i],my_list[i+1] = my_list[i+1],my_list[i]
               switched = True

super_simple_sort(some_list)
print some_list
```

is a very simple sorting implementation ... that is equivelent to yours but takes advantage of some things to speed it up (we only need one for loop, and we only need to repeat as long as the list is out of order,  also python doesnt require a temp var for swapping values)

since its changing the actual array values you actually dont even need to return

Comment: I implemented the code you suggested and it works fantastically so thank you! But it sorts the list like 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 instead of 5, 4, 3, 2, 1. Do you know what I would need to do to change it? I've tried messing around with certain parts of it but I can't seem to get it to change. Can you help?
EDIT: Ignore this, I actually managed to work it out moments after sending this. But still, many thanks