# Sort names as well as scores

Tags: python, list, sorting, file-handling

I'm a computing student who posted [a question here the other day about helping me with my function to sort scores in order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21915070/custom-sort-method-in-python-is-not-sorting-list-properly) and I got some great help and it now works but I would also like it to sort the names according to the scores (so if James gets 10 then it prints "James   10". Right now what is happening is that the scores are sorting and printing to the screen properly but the names are just printing in the order that they are entered. I've tried this:

```
def sortlist():
global scorelist, namelist, hss
namelist = []
scorelist = []
hs = open("hstname.txt", "r")
namelist = hs.read().splitlines()
hss = open("hstscore.txt","r")
for line in hss:
    scorelist.append(int(line))

switched = True
while switched:
    switched = False
    for i in range(len(scorelist)-1):
        for j in range(len(namelist)-1):
            if scorelist[i] < scorelist[i+1]:
                scorelist[i],scorelist[i+1] = scorelist[i+1],scorelist[i]
                namelist[j],namelist[j+1] = namelist[j+1],namelist[j]
                switched = True
```

The score part works fine and it took me ages to get it and I'm not allowed to use a pre defined function like .sort(). Can anyone offer any help/advice? Or if you can see what I'm doing wrong then can you offer a solution? I can't work this out for the life of me

Comment: Do you need to have 2 lists or could you combine them into one?

Comment: @IanAuld I originally had one list but through the course of this project I have made it into two lists and I would prefer to keep it like that because I understand it and it's pretty much too late to go changing too much stuff

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use nested loops in order to go through both lists.

Since you should be manipulating the two lists in exactly the same way, you should only be using one `for` loop, and using the `i` variable to index into both lists.

If yoy turn this:

```
    for i in range(len(scorelist)-1):
        for j in range(len(namelist)-1):
            if scorelist[i] < scorelist[i+1]:
                scorelist[i],scorelist[i+1] = scorelist[i+1],scorelist[i]
                namelist[j],namelist[j+1] = namelist[j+1],namelist[j]
                switched = True
```

into this:

```
    for i in range(len(scorelist)-1):
        if scorelist[i] < scorelist[i+1]:
            scorelist[i],scorelist[i+1] = scorelist[i+1],scorelist[i]
            namelist[i],namelist[i+1] = namelist[i+1],namelist[i]
            switched = True
```

then you should get both lists sorted as you want them.

The only time when this will cause an error is if your two lists are of different lengths. If `namelist` is somehow shorter than `scorelist` then this code will throw an exception. You could guard against that by checking before your sort routine that

```
len(scorelist) == len(namelist)
```

Answer (score 0):

Imagine, you have a function that returns a single sorted list e.g. here's an implementation of [Quicksort algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort) in Python:

```
def qsorted(L):
    return L and (qsorted([x for x in L[1:] if x < L[0]]) + # lesser items
                  [L[0]] +                                  # pivot
                  qsorted([x for x in L[1:] if x >= L[0]])) # greater or equal
```

Then you could use it to sort your `scorelist`:

```
qsorted_scorelist = qsorted(scorelist)
```

To sort `namelist` according to the order of `scorelist`; you could use [Schwartzian transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwartzian_transform):

```
qsorted_namelist = [name for score, name in qsorted(zip(scorelist, namelist))]
```

Note that the *same* function `qsorted()` is used in both case: to sort the `scorelist` along and to sort both lists together. You should try to extract common functionality into separate functions instead of modifying your sorting algorithm inplace for a slighty different task.

To test that the result is correct; you could use the builtin `sorted()` function:

```
 sorted_namelist = [name for score, name in sorted(zip(scorelist, namelist))]
```